# Exponential function in a Tkinter gui

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, exponential

I am having a problem trying to define a exponential function in a Tkinter gui. My Gui is composed by three combo boxes where I can choose different numbers. When I select all numbers it displays a result based on a exponential function. What I mean is as follows:

- Select NumberA #Combobox 1
- Select NumberB #Combobox 2
- Select NumberC #Combobox 3

  ```
  Result = exp[(-NumberA/NumberB)* NumberC]
  ```

What I have so far is as follows, but it doesn't work:

```
#Main Selection
def exponential(*args):
    try:
        product.set('%g' %math.exp((float(Num_A.get())/float(Num_B.get())*float(Num_C.get()),2)))
    except ValueError:
        pass

## variables
NumA = StringVar() 
NumB = StringVar() 
NumC = StringVar()

product= DoubleVar()

#Combo boxes, 
#NumA NumB and NumC are similar
ttk.Label(stepTen, text="Select A):").grid(column =3, row = 0)
NumA_Select = Combobox(stepTen, values=("0.1", "0.2", "0.3","0.4",),textvariable=Num_OneT)
NumA_Select.grid(column=4, row=0, columnspan="5", sticky="nswe")
NumA.trace("w",exponential)

## display results
ttk.Label(stepTen, text = "Exponential Dist result:").grid(column = 3, row = 12)
ttk.Label(stepTen, textvariable=product).grid(column = 4, row = 12)

#End Code
root.mainloop()
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does the program crash? Does it compute the wrong number? Does your computer freeze? Also, you need to check the formatting of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example code, nowhere do you set `NumA`, `NumB`, or `NumC` to a value, and those variables aren't associated with any widgets. Plus, you create variables named `NumA`, `NumB` and `NumC`, but in your function you're using `Num_A`, `Num_B` and `Num_C`.

Comment: Dear Brian, thank you for your prompt response... when I was copying I made a mistake, where I put Num_A I meant NumA as well as for NumB and NumC, and Num_OneT is in fact NumA. I apologize for my mistake. thank you

Comment: @Hector: the problem remains that you don't set `NumB` or `NumbC`. I suggest in the `except` block that you print out errors rather than ignoring them. That way you'll see the reason why the value is failing to be computed.